# Search from/Name-Transport Date

Tags: ms-access, vba

The Search by Name works, but when I'm trying also to filter by Date and it appears this error :

Run-time error '3075':

```
Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression 'DriverFirst Like'*paul*'TransportDate Like '*4/5/2015*".
```

Below you have the code:

```
Private Sub Command33_Click()

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim boolBefore As Boolean

    strSQL = ""
    boolBefore = False

    If Len(Me.txtSrch) > 1 Then
        If (boolBefore) Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " AND "
        End If

        strSQL = strSQL & "DriverFirst Like '*" & Me.txtSrch & "*'"
    End If

    If Len(Me.fromDate) > 1 Then
        If (boolBefore) Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " AND "
        End If

        strSQL = strSQL & "TransportDate Like '*" & Me.fromDate & "*'"
        boolBefore = True
    End If

    Me.Form.Filter = strSQL
    Me.Form.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TransportDate Like fromDate

doesn't make much sense. Also you must use a properly formatted string expression for the date value, thus:

```
strSQL = strSQL & " TransportDate = #" & Format(Me!fromDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

Answer (score 1):

You've left asterisk wildcard characters where you are concatenating in the date. I believe an Access query should be using hashmarks (e.g. #) to wrap a date and a direct compare rather than a pattern match.

```
strSQL = strSQL & "TransportDate = #" & Me.fromDate & "#"
```

Comment: Again is marked with yellow this    Me.Form.Filter = strSQL